# Motion ffmpeg_open: url_fopen - error opening file (check access rights to target directory)

Tags: motion, permissions, file

I am trying to record my motion videos inside the directory `/media/pi/camera`. This directory has the following permissions:

> drwxrwxr-x  2 motion motion 4096 Aug  9 20:04 camera

I set the same permissions as my previous directory for motion videos had (`/var/lib/motion`).

I configured `target_dir` inside `/etc/motion/motion.conf` as: `target_dir /media/pi/camera` (I am literally copying and pasting here).

Finally, I run `sudo service motion start` like before, and I am keep getting the following error:

> [1] [ERR] [ENC] [Aug 09 20:38:56] ffmpeg_open: url_fopen - error
>   opening file /media/pi/camera/01-20170809203856.avi ... check access
>   rights to target directory: [1] [ERR] [EVT] [Aug 09 20:38:56]
>   event_ffmpeg_newfile: ffopen_open error creating (new) file
>   [/media/pi/camera/01-20170809203856.avi]:

I also tried to run `sudo /etc/init.d/motion start` but it did not help.

However, if I run `sudo motion` then it works (it records a few seconds and saves a video normally inside `/media/pi/camera`.

My best guess was that `sudo service motion start` starts `motion` as another user. But even then, I gave `777` permissions to the folder and it still doesn't want to save videos there.
I use `motion Version 3.2.12+git20140228`.

Has anybody got any clue what I am doing wrong, or is that a problem with motion?